# What control is used for, say, Ringtone selection in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As I understand, it's recommended to use the LongListSelector for a list representation in WP8.

But what is on the top of the list? What control is used for, say, Ringtone selection in settings (it is something on the top of the LongListSelector, am I right?)

Comment: A ListPicker perhaps?

Comment: Aha, is this from Windows Phone toolkit?

Comment: Yes. Other controls from toolkit are listed here. phone.codeplex.com. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListPicker.

Find it in the [toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The question was "What control is used for, say, Ringtone selection in settings". ListPicker answers that :)